# Importing multiple python files in subfolders

Tags: python

I want to import a python file `Loader` within a subfolder `sub1`. This file that I want to import, imports another file `detector` within that same subfolder. However, `Loader` gives the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'detector'

I've tried using the exec command in Python and

```
import sub1.Loader
```

The folder structure looks like this:

```
Project
    | 
    +-- File_for_loading_Loader.py
    | 
    +-- sub1
         |  
         +-- __init__.py
         +-- Loader.py
         +-- detector.py
```

Can anyone help?

**Edit**

I now use:

```
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["python", "Loader.py"], cwd="sub1")
```

which does the trick nicely. No need for relative imports etc.

Comment: How are you importing `detector` inside your Loader.py?

Comment: `from detector import detect_faces`

Comment: Uhhh, there seems to be something wrong with your package structure. The name `sub1` implies that it's a *sub*module, but `Project` doesn't look like a module. If `Project` *is* a module, your import should look like `import Project.sub1.Loader`.

Comment: And inside your package you should be using relative imports: `from .detector import detect_faces`.

Comment: Project is just the main folder I put stuff into. It is the main folder of my repo.

Comment: Aran, using relative imports gives ` __main__ is not a package`

Answer (score 1):

Since you created `sub1` as module you have to import files from it always like `sub1.<module_name>`.

So for you it should be `from sub1.detector import detect_faces` in your Loader.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import loader in `File_for_loading_Loader.py` by using `import sub1.Loader as abc`.

And in Loader.py you need to import detector by using `import sub1.detector as xyz`.